# Can i force visual studio to use MinGW compiler instead of its default compiler?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, qt, mingw

I am developing desktop application in visual studio 2008 using c# for a machine which cuts the material in two parts using laser. At the electronics hand my friend uses a QT programming language to made a library for serial communication and axis handling. As we know QT programming uses a MinGW compiler while C# uses a VC++. There is many ways to use QT Library in C# like using Qt MSVC add-in you can compile library in Visual Studio's compiler, I have tried and also got succeeded in this, but there are some limitations of QT library to execute functionality like threads,etc on MSVC compiler. So now I think, if my C# application able to compile on MinGw compiler using Visual Studio IDE then it becomes very easy to execute all QT library functionality on windows platform through my code.

In simple words, Is there is any way to change the compiler of Visual Studio to MinGW for compilation successfully code of both different platform?

Comment: MinGW is simply a Windows port of [GCC](https://gcc.gnu.org/) GCC compiles C, C++, Objective-C, Fortran, Java, Ada, and Go. It doesn't compile C#

Answer (score 0):

**Related:** [How do I set GNU G++ compiler in Visual studio 2008](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3400277/how-do-i-set-gnu-g-compiler-in-visual-studio-2008)

**Additional Advice:**

I've used Qt for years and never had a threading issue using `QThread` and the MSVC or MinGW toolchain.  My advice would be to look into the `QtCreator` IDE, it is an optional install in the tools section of Qt.  It has come a long way, especially on Windows and Linux.  With the proper configuration you can test side-by-side compilations using different toolchains.

I made the switch from Visual Studio IDE a few years back and haven't regretted it.