# Specifying multiple build rules/tools per input file in a VS2008 project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008

I have a pre-processor that I'd like to run on my .cpp/.h files before compiling them.  I created a Custom Build Rule and applied it to my project.  This successfully runs the pre-processor, but it does not actually compile the files afterwards.  So what I'd like to do is run my custom rule first and then run the C/C++ Compiler Tool as default.

I could do this with a pre-build step, but then I'd have to force processing of all source files in the project, when I really just want to process the source files that have changed.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

With advanced builds you are generally better off using an external makefile.  You can add this in to MS2008 as a custom tool.

See: [Good techniques to use Makefiles in VisualStudio?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/593906/good-techniques-to-use-makefiles-in-visualstudio)

If you do not want to use external scripts, you may be able to get what you want by having two projects within your solution with *the same files* in them.  You make one project a dependency of the other.  In the dependent project use your custom build rule, in the top project do the real compile/build.  Caveat emptor - I've not tried this.

Let us know how you get on.